# Why is this code not working? There is no Output

Tags: java

```
 public class Main
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x=8, y=0, z=1; //random integers
    
  if (x > 0 && y < 0)
  
 {
  if (x==8)
   System.out.print("Yes");
  else if (z > 0)
  System.out.print("No");
 }
 
    }
}
```

why does this code does not print an output ?

it should print " yes " or " no " because the first if is wrong ?

Comment: To get to code responsible for printing we first need to pass condition described in `if (x > 0 && y < 0)`. But since `int x=8, y=0` condition `x > 0 && y < 0` is evaluated as `8 > 0 && 0 < 0` which is `true && false` which is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

&& operator only return true if and only if both of the operands are true
That is,

```
 true  && true   = true 
 true  && false  = false
 false && true  = false
 false && false = false
```

In your code since `y= 0` the first if condition itself is not satisfied ,so you have to replace `y<0` with `y<=0`

Answer (score 0):

```java
if (x > 0 && y < 0)
```

Your `y` value is 0, so the test `y < 0` return false, you do not enter in your first if.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the second `if` and delete the block (`{ }`) that was opened above the second `if`.

Answer (score -1):

you should change this line

```
if (x > 0 && y < 0)
```

to this

```
if (x > 0 && y <= 0)
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit `=<` into `<=`, as the former is not a Java operator. Also, your answer could be improved by explaining a bit why/how this actually fixes OP's problem.

Comment: Why? The code might be right but his expectations wrong.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen because in the code he said smaller than 0 in y < 0,
zero doesn't exist!

Comment: @AliHasaniFar So why did you undo the edit and revert back to the incorrect, non-operator?

Comment: @ali code might be wrong.

Comment: can you explain why this would work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You should write it like this to get it to work:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int x=8, y=0, z=1; //random integers
    
        if (x > 0 && y < 0)
            System.out.print("Yes");
 
        else if (z > 0)
            System.out.print("No");
 
    }
}
```